# systemtap cannot work on Ubuntu: "unable to find a suitable compile server"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemtap

When I run `systemtap` on my Ubuntu, I always get this failure:

```
lwtools# ./biolatency-nd.stp 
Using a compile server.
Unable to find a suitable compile server.  [man stap-server]
No servers online to select from.
Passes: via server failed.  Try again with another '-v' option.
The kernel on your system requires modules to be signed for loading.
The module created by compiling your script must be signed by a systemtap compile-server.  [man stap-server]
--use-server was automatically selected in order to request compilation by a compile-server.
Tip: /usr/share/doc/systemtap/README.Debian should help you get started.
```

Comment: So did you have a look at `man stap-server` and `/usr/share/doc/systemtap/README.Debian` as suggested? You will need to provide a [mcve] as noone knows what `biolatency-nd.stp` is.

Answer (score 0):

On systems where SecureBoot is enabled, systemtap relies on a compile-server (`stap-server` service) to get the kernel module files signed.  Without those signatures, SecureBoot kernels may reject the modules entirely.  See https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SecureBoot .

It is possible that this Ubuntu kernel is compiled in such a way that even in SecureBoot mode, unsigned .ko files may be loaded.  Even so, once set up, the secureboot-capable `stap-server` can work.